# How to use AsyncCrudAppService from client side

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

[CrudAppService and AsyncCrudAppService Classes](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Application-Services#crudappservice-and-asynccrudappservice-classes) explains how to inherit from the crud base class, but it doesn't explain how to use it from the client/JS to either:-

1. Retrieve a specific page
2. Retrieve all pages

How can I use AsyncCrudAppService from the client side?

Comment: I see from the ABP source that I can pass skipCount and maxResultCount to answer the first question. And I could pass in maxResultCount: 9999 to answer the second, but doesn't seem very eloquent

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use and display PagedResultDto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47879378/how-to-use-and-display-pagedresultdto)

Answer (score 0):

You can use skipCount and maxResultCount to retrieve sets of pages. Suggest adding this to ABP documentation though