# How to use and display PagedResultDto

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

Using ASPNet Boilerplate, and returning a pagedResultSetDto with the below code, how do I display the page links?

```
 public PagedResultDto<ArticleDto> GetAll()
    {
        var articleCount = articleRepository.Count();

        var t = articleRepository.GetAllIncluding(x => x.articleImage).Include(x => x.Category).Where(
                x => x.PublishFrom <= DateTime.Now &&
                x.PublishTo >= DateTime.Now &&
                 x.Status == PostStatus.Published &&
                 x.IsDeleted == false
                ).OrderByDescending(x=> x.PublishFrom).ToList();

        return new PagedResultDto<ArticleDto>
        {
            TotalCount = articleCount,
            Items = t.MapTo<List<ArticleDto>>()
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, take in [`IPagedResultRequest`](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Data-Transfer-Objects#DocHelperDtoInterfaces) as input:

```cs
// using Abp.Linq.Extensions;

public PagedResultDto<ArticleDto> GetAll(PagedResultRequestDto input)
{
    var articleCount = articleRepository.Count();

    var t = articleRepository
            .GetAllIncluding(x => x.articleImage)
            .Include(x => x.Category)
            .Where(x =>
                x.PublishFrom <= DateTime.Now &&
                x.PublishTo >= DateTime.Now &&
                x.Status == PostStatus.Published &&
                x.IsDeleted == false
            )
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.PublishFrom)
            .PageBy(input) // Page by SkipCount and MaxResultCount
            .ToList();

    return new PagedResultDto<ArticleDto>
    {
        TotalCount = articleCount,
        Items = t.MapTo<List<ArticleDto>>()
    };
}
```

Then create your own links to pass in `SkipCount`, e.g. `GetAll?SkipCount=10` for page 2.

`MaxResultCount` has a [default value](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/912e320aecc29ad19531895cb69d0ab79db73d9c/src/Abp/Application/Services/Dto/LimitedResultRequestDto.cs#L11) of `10`.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate it according to the result of GetAll(). 
You request how many records you want. Let's say 10 (default value). 
It returns TotalCount and Items (=records). Let's say TotalCount = 95. Divide 95/10 = 9.5 ~=> 10 pages. Show 10 links. While 9 pages will show 10 records, last page will have 5 records. That